# Jenkins TFS plugin deploy successful changes only

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I like to do partial builds of changes from today and deploy them on other environments (TST, Support or UAT, Prod) can jenkins do this on its own?

Answer (score 0):

It can, but a better question is should it. Jenkins is a build system and not a deploy system. You should instead use a release management tool like octopus deploy or release management for visual studio.

http://nakedalm.com/blog/create-release-management-pipeline-professional-developers/

Comment: I like that Jenkins has octopus deploy plugin.I think I'll try that route. So can octopus deploy only changed files?

Comment: octopus deploy is not free :(